# Searching for a key and printing a value from a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have created a Hashmap with a String key representing memberID (which is a numeric value) and the values are instances of Athlete objects such as name, address and age.

I need to write a method which takes a String argument representing the memberId and return the associated values.  I am struggling with the method, in particular how to return only the values associated with the key if found.  My method below returns all Athlete values after a particular key entry is found and I am not sure how to isolate to just the key values where a match is found.   Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

```
public void findAthlete(String aNum)
   {     
      if(athletes.containsKey(aNum))
      {
            System.out.println("Key Value Present: " + athletes);
      }
      else 
      {

         System.out.println("Key Value not present within data");
      }
   }
```

Comment: athletes.get(aNum) gets the athlete with the given key, is this what you are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:  `stadium` is an instance of the `Stadium` class.

```
Optional<Athlete> op = stadium.getAthlete("some key");
if (op.isPresent()) {
     Athlete at = op.get();
} else {
   // take action if no athlete found
}

// within the Stadium class

Map<String, Athlete> athletes = new HashMap<>();
public Optional<Athlete> getAthlete(String key) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(athletes.get(key));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand your question but I think what you want to do is to extract the value from the map, so lets say you have an Athlete class, your find method should return that

```
public Athlete findAthlete(String aNum){...}
```

Then you can return the athlete if found:

```
return athletes.getOrDefault(aNum, null);
```

You can return `null` on an empty `Athlete` or an `Optional<Athlete>`, whatever fits your needs

Comment: Apologies @petrubear I should have specified, I have another class called Stadium which holds the hashmap and the method I mentioned above should be within the Stadium class.